# How can I use ggplot2 and stat_bin to make a bar chart that includes numeric levels with no observations

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data as an ordered factor, with levels 1,2,3,4,5. (This is Likert scale data.)  I would like to use ggplot to create a bar chart of counts, but this must include all the levels, even the ones with zero count. Here is an example data frame with zero count at the level equal to 2.

```
library(ggplot2)

foo <- structure(list(feed.n.1.50..3. = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), .Names = "answers", row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = "data.frame")

table(foo) # satisfy myself the level 2 has zero entries

ggplot(foo,aes(answers)) + geom_bar(stat="bin") # stat="bin" is not needed, but there for clarity
```

`stat_bin()` has a parameter `drop`, documented as

```
drop: If TRUE, remove all bins with zero counts
```

The default is FALSE, though, so I expected the levels to be kept.  Is there a simple way to use ggplot to keep all the levels of the factor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dropping of level is done by scales (default), so use `scale_x_discrete()` with argument `drop=FALSE` to show all levels.

```
ggplot(foo,aes(answers)) + geom_bar()+
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: +1. This works even if you're using `qplot` -- just add the `scale_x_discrete` after the end of the qplot call.